# How do I call different scopes with link_to buttons using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a project where users can create events and sign up to be guests at other user's events.  The profile features personal information on the left and a feed of events on the right.  Underneath the profile, I'd like to add links that sort the events in different ways(future, past, user created, ect.)  It would look something like the section under categories in this template:
[Example](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Moderna/blog.html#)

I'd like to do this using ajax calls.  I already have most of the scopes built in the event model that I want.  I just need a way to update the feed gracefully.
Sorry if I'm not describing this well. I'm very new at rails.

Here's the relevant code.
Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  # == Constants ============================================================

  # == Attributes ===========================================================

  # == Extensions ===========================================================

  # == Relationships ========================================================
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :invitations, foreign_key: :attended_event_id
  has_many :attendees, through: :invitations, source: :attendee
  # == Validations ==========================================================

  # == Scopes ===============================================================
  scope :upcoming, -> { where("start_time >= ?", Time.now) }
  scope :past, -> { where("start_time < ?", Time.now) }
  scope :soonest_first, -> { order(:start_time) }
  scope :most_recent_first, -> { order(start_time: :desc) }
  # == Callbacks ============================================================

  # == Class Methods ========================================================

  # == Instance Methods =====================================================

end
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #@events = @user.attended_events.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @upcoming_events = @user.events.upcoming.soonest_first
    @past_events = @user.events.past.most_recent_first
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, 
                                   :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Relevant portion of view:

```
 <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="sidebar">

          <h3 class="sidebar-title"><%= @user.username%></h3>

          <div class="sidebar-item categories">
          <h4 class="sidebar-title">Events</h4>
          <ul>
            WHERE I WANT LINKS!!!
          </ul>

          </div><!-- End sidebar categories-->

        </div><!-- End sidebar -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You want it through an ajax, so I guess you will use a `js.erb` file to just update the part showing events right?

There is one way I can think of is to add a `index.js.erb` file under your events directory, and do something like `<%= link_to 'future', events_path(filter: 'future'), remote: true %>` and in the events controller you can use the `filter` param to filter the events. In order to let rails differentiate from Ajax calls to normal request, you want to put the logic in `format.js {}`

Comment: I will try that tomorrow when I have some time off.  Thank you.

Comment: If this worked out it would be lovely if you could accept my answer bro~ @Eojo

Comment: I did more research and ended up just using query strings, which I wasn't aware of when I wrote this post.  Unfortunately, I think I'm too much of a noob to mess with ajax for now.  Thank you for the response though. @Awlter